# ListView/RecyclerView virtualization

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

`ListView` derives from `AbsListView`.
Are there any examples of UI virtualization?

What I mean by virtualization is:

If there are 1 million items to display, there is a much smaller amount of items (20) in memory, enough so that they fill all the visible content of the ListView. 
Also, very important, the scroll is computed correctly, it looks as if there's 1 million items to scroll.

Also, same question RecyclerView, if there any examples of UI virtualization for it.

Comment: This is exactly what RecyclerView already does.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks. I;m aware that RecycleView is the recommended way, but is this possible with ListView too?

Comment: RecyclerView was made to do this because ListView couldn't. It's even part of the name.

Comment: Maybe just with AbsListView?

Comment: AbsListView is just the base of ListView. There are no functional differences.